# Using prompt, choose number of numbers, add that number of numbers to an array, then display total

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, prompt

I'm trying to load a prompt that asks how many numbers the user wants to enter, then a prompt will popup the amount of times they entered, and they will be able to enter a number each time that goes into an array and then one last alert box showing the sum.

How can I build this array and then get the total sum?

To get the first numberOfNumbers I used this:

```js
function hello()
{
var numberOfNumbers=prompt("How many numbers would you like to add?")
alert(y)
}

var sum = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfNumbers; i++) {
   sum.push(i);
}
```

Comment: numberOfNumbers doesn't exist out of scope of the function block.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to get others to do your homework for you...

Answer (score 1):

Why would you build the array?

```js
var numberOfNumbers = parseInt(prompt("How many numbers would you like to add?"));

if(isNaN(numberOfNumbers) || numberOfNumbers <= 0) {
  alert("Invalid number!");
}
else {
  var sum = 0, i;
  for (i = 1; i <= numberOfNumbers; i++) {
     sum += i;
  }
  alert(sum);
}
```

Also, as @JohnRummuel pointed out, in your code `numberOfNumbers` doesn't exist out of scope of the function block, so the `for` loop does not "see" it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var numberOfNumbers = parseInt(prompt("How many numbers would you like to add?"));
alert(numberOfNumbers);

var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfNumbers; i++) {
   sum += parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"));
}
alert("The sum of numbers you entered is " + sum);
```

Comment: I'm glad that it helped.  If it worked perfectly, please upvote it and accept it as the correct answer to your question.  That is how this site works.  When you ask a question and get the answer you were looking for, you can upvote it and accept it, so later visitors to the same thread can immediately get to a solution that worked - and the people who provided the correct answer get the credit for it (which helps when trying to get other people to answer THEIR questions).  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want to do?

```
function hello() { 
    var numberOfNumbers = prompt("How many numbers would you like to add?"); 
    return parseint(numberOfNumbers, 10);
}

function sumNumbers() {
    var numbers = []; 
    var number = 0; 
    var numberOfNumbers = hello(); 
    for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfNumbers; i++) { 
        number = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number to add"), 10); 
        numbers.push(number); 
    } 
    alert(numbers.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; })) ; 
}
```

Comment: There is no need for an array or to split this into multiple functions.  Also, your functions should have more accurately descriptive names (try to avoid names like 'hello'.  Also, the numbers.reduce(function(a, b) line is total overkill.  Remember, simpler is better!

Comment: @Stan I used the name 'hello' because that's the name chosen by the person who asked the question. Said person also specifically asked for an array, so I demonstrated how the values of an array can be summed, which the asker didn't know about. Seriously, no need to downvote it when it does exactly what the person wants while taking into account specifics he/she wrote about.

Comment: The downvote was solely for "alert(numbers.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }));"  And while I appreciate that you were answering his question, he is obviously pretty inexperienced and doesn't seem to understand what he needs or wants to accomplish his objective - so it's better to provide a workable solution rather than placate him by providing exactly what was requested.  I do realize that this approach is exclusive to questions like the one in this post.  Maybe I shouldn't have downvoted your answer, so I apologize for that, but it won't let me undo it.

Comment: @Stan Yes, I understood your approach, perhaps I should've made mine more explicit with something like "this is not the best way to do it, I'll just demonstrate how you can do some of the things you asked in your question...". Anyway, at least the guy will have both.

Comment: No worries - he's probably going to get in trouble because it'll be obvious he didn't write it when he turns in his homework lol